# How to create a new record based on form data and an existing record that I have selected?

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to create a database that has a table of client information, and a second table with information about interactions with that client on a specific date.

So I've created ClientTable, and AppointmentTable, with a lookup on AppointmentTable to link to the client data.  The database functions, and using a query form, I can make appointment notes and update client information.

But I need to have a simple interface, so I can specify a date, search for a client, and create a new record on AppointmentTable with the date and client already set.

I'm struggling to know if I am supposed to do this on a query form, or on the form for AppointmentTable.  It's been decades since I've used Access and I'm pretty rusty.  I don't need anything fancy, and I'd prefer to avoid VBA, as this seems like it should be a straight forward database feature.

Comment: You could have a form/subform arrangement. Locate client on main form. Enter date in new record row of subform. The client search can be done with intrinsic ribbon and right click menu tools. No VBA.

Comment: SO is a site for programming related questions, not general software support. You're looking for [su] instead. You can find more information about this site in the [help].